# Barnyard 2 install failing on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, snort

I'm new to OpenBSD, but I'm having issues with getting Barnyard to install after running the `make` command. I've ran `./configure` and `./configure --with-mysql` and both end up with the same error when running `make`. I've seen mention of daq not being installed or libpcap and I've recompiled those as well. Running version 2.0.6 of DAQ and 1.7.4 of libcap.

I've done a vanilla install of DAQ as described in the [installation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/096/original/snort-openbsd5x-298x.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1468248051&Signature=uO5BhcGGWs9BltA3Pvngv6qPdUo%3D) manual.

```
./configure --with-libpcap-libraries=/usr/local/lib --with-libpcap-includes=/usr/local/include
make
make install
ldconfig -m -v -r /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
```

If I'm understanding what ldconfig does, when I do an ldconfig -r I do not see anything related to daq. Could that be a part of the issue?

Dump of messages from ./configure and make from Barnyard2. What am I missing, or more importantly, what should I be looking for as clues to the issue?

```
# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.9
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.9
checking how to print strings... print -r
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... no
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.9 file names to x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.9 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-openbsd5.9 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... match_pattern /lib[^/]+(\.so\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|\.so|_pic\.a)$
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... print -r --
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... openbsd5.9 ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) none
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for bison... bison
checking for flex... flex
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/sockio.h usability... yes
checking sys/sockio.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sockio.h... yes
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for floor in -lm... yes
checking for ceil in -lm... yes
checking for inet_ntoa in -lnsl... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking whether printf must be declared... no
checking whether fprintf must be declared... no
checking whether syslog must be declared... no
checking whether puts must be declared... no
checking whether fputs must be declared... no
checking whether fputc must be declared... no
checking whether fopen must be declared... no
checking whether fclose must be declared... no
checking whether fwrite must be declared... no
checking whether fflush must be declared... no
checking whether getopt must be declared... no
checking whether bzero must be declared... no
checking whether bcopy must be declared... no
checking whether memset must be declared... no
checking whether strtol must be declared... no
checking whether strcasecmp must be declared... no
checking whether strncasecmp must be declared... no
checking whether strerror must be declared... no
checking whether perror must be declared... no
checking whether socket must be declared... no
checking whether sendto must be declared... no
checking whether vsnprintf must be declared... no
checking whether snprintf must be declared... no
checking whether strtoul must be declared... no
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for strlcpy... yes
checking for strlcat... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for vswprintf... yes
checking for wprintf... yes
checking size of char... 1
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long int... 8
checking size of long long int... 8
checking size of unsigned int... 4
checking size of unsigned long int... 8
checking size of unsigned long long int... 8
checking for u_int8_t... yes
checking for u_int16_t... yes
checking for u_int32_t... yes
checking for u_int64_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking for int8_t... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for int32_t... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for INADDR_NONE... yes
checking for __FUNCTION__... yes
checking pcap.h usability... yes
checking pcap.h presence... yes
checking for pcap.h... yes
checking for pcap_datalink in -lpcap... yes
checking for sparc... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sfutil/Makefile
config.status: creating src/input-plugins/Makefile
config.status: creating src/output-plugins/Makefile
config.status: creating etc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating rpm/Makefile
config.status: creating schemas/Makefile
config.status: creating m4/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
#
# make
make  all-recursive
Making all in src
Making all in sfutil
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..  -I..    -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -c -o sf_iph.o sf_iph.c
In file included from sf_iph.c:29:
../decode.h:48:17: error: daq.h: No such file or directory
../decode.h:49:23: error: sfbpf_dlt.h: No such file or directory
In file included from sf_iph.c:29:
../decode.h:1617: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
../decode.h:1851: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1851: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1852: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1852: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1853: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1853: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1854: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1854: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1891: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1891: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1892: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1892: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1893: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1893: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1894: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1894: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1895: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1895: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1896: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1896: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1897: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1897: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1898: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1898: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1899: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1899: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1900: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1900: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1901: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1901: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1902: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1902: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h:1903: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'DAQ_PktHdr_t'
../decode.h:1903: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
../decode.h: In function 'PacketWasCooked':
../decode.h:1941: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h: In function 'IsPortscanPacket':
../decode.h:1946: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h:1946: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'pseudo_type'
../decode.h: In function 'GetEventProto':
../decode.h:1952: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ps_proto'
../decode.h:1953: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph'
../decode.h:1953: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph'
../decode.h: In function 'PacketHasFullPDU':
../decode.h:1958: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h: In function 'PacketHasStartOfPDU':
../decode.h:1963: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h: In function 'PacketHasPAFPayload':
../decode.h:1968: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h: In function 'PacketIsRebuilt':
../decode.h:1973: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'packet_flags'
../decode.h: In function 'SetExtraData':
../decode.h:1978: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'xtradata_mask'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_src':
sf_iph.c:57: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_src':
sf_iph.c:64: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_dst':
sf_iph.c:71: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_dst':
sf_iph.c:79: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_toc':
sf_iph.c:87: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c:87: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_toc':
sf_iph.c:97: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:97: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_hops':
sf_iph.c:105: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_hops':
sf_iph.c:112: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_len':
sf_iph.c:122: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_len':
sf_iph.c:129: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_id':
sf_iph.c:135: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_extension_count'
sf_iph.c:138: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_extensions'
sf_iph.c:138: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_frag_index'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_next':
sf_iph.c:152: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_next':
sf_iph.c:158: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_off':
sf_iph.c:164: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_extension_count'
sf_iph.c:167: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_extensions'
sf_iph.c:167: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6_frag_index'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip6_ret_ver':
sf_iph.c:180: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c:180: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip6_ret_ver':
sf_iph.c:185: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:185: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_dst':
sf_iph.c:191: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_dst':
sf_iph.c:197: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_src':
sf_iph.c:203: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_src':
sf_iph.c:209: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_tos':
sf_iph.c:216: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_tos':
sf_iph.c:223: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_ttl':
sf_iph.c:230: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_ttl':
sf_iph.c:237: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_len':
sf_iph.c:244: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_len':
sf_iph.c:251: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_id':
sf_iph.c:258: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_id':
sf_iph.c:265: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_proto':
sf_iph.c:272: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_proto':
sf_iph.c:279: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_off':
sf_iph.c:284: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_off':
sf_iph.c:289: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_ver':
sf_iph.c:294: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_ver':
sf_iph.c:299: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph'
sf_iph.c: In function 'ip4_ret_hlen':
sf_iph.c:304: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph'
sf_iph.c: In function 'orig_ip4_ret_hlen':
sf_iph.c:309: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph'
sf_iph.c: In function '_set_callbacks':
sf_iph.c:382: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'iph_api'
sf_iph.c:384: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'iph_api'
sf_iph.c:386: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'family'
sf_iph.c:391: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:393: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:395: error: 'struct _Packet' has no member named 'orig_family'
sf_iph.c: In function 'sfiph_build':
sf_iph.c:414: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'family'
sf_iph.c:416: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph_api'
sf_iph.c:417: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:417: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:418: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph_api'
sf_iph.c:419: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:419: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:421: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:421: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'iph_api'
sf_iph.c:422: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_family'
sf_iph.c:422: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'family'
sf_iph.c:434: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:435: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:436: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:437: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'actual_ip_len'
sf_iph.c:437: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:437: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:438: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip4h'
sf_iph.c:438: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:447: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:448: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:449: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:450: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'actual_ip_len'
sf_iph.c:450: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:450: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:451: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'ip6h'
sf_iph.c:451: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_ip6h'
sf_iph.c: In function 'sfiph_orig_build':
sf_iph.c:465: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:465: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:467: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:467: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:468: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:468: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:470: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:470: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:472: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:472: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:473: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'outer_orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:473: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_iph_api'
sf_iph.c:485: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:486: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:487: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:488: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'actual_ip_len'
sf_iph.c:488: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:488: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:489: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:489: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip4h'
sf_iph.c:498: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:499: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:500: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:501: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'actual_ip_len'
sf_iph.c:501: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:501: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:502: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'orig_ip6h'
sf_iph.c:502: error: 'Packet' has no member named 'inner_orig_ip6h'
*** Error 1 in src/sfutil (Makefile:372 'sf_iph.o')
*** Error 1 in src (Makefile:521 'all-recursive')
*** Error 1 in . (Makefile:435 'all-recursive')
*** Error 1 in /usr/local/src/barnyard2-master (Makefile:342 'all')
#
```

ldconfig dump

```
# ldconfig -r
/var/run/ld.so.hints:
        search directories: /usr/lib
        0:-lformw.6.0 => /usr/lib/libformw.so.6.0
        1:-levent.4.1 => /usr/lib/libevent.so.4.1
        2:-liberty.12.0 => /usr/lib/libiberty.so.12.0
        3:-lcurses.14.0 => /usr/lib/libcurses.so.14.0
        4:-lncurses.14.0 => /usr/lib/libncurses.so.14.0
        5:-lpanel.6.0 => /usr/lib/libpanel.so.6.0
        6:-lform.6.0 => /usr/lib/libform.so.6.0
        7:-lfuse.1.1 => /usr/lib/libfuse.so.1.1
        8:-lexpat.11.0 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.11.0
        9:-lpanelw.6.0 => /usr/lib/libpanelw.so.6.0
        10:-lpcap.8.0 => /usr/lib/libpcap.so.8.0
        11:-lncursesw.14.0 => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.14.0
        12:-lc.84.2 => /usr/lib/libc.so.84.2
        13:-lperl.17.1 => /usr/lib/libperl.so.17.1
        14:-lpthread.20.1 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.20.1
        15:-lossaudio.4.0 => /usr/lib/libossaudio.so.4.0
        16:-lradius.1.0 => /usr/lib/libradius.so.1.0
        17:-ledit.5.2 => /usr/lib/libedit.so.5.2
        18:-lmenu.6.0 => /usr/lib/libmenu.so.6.0
        19:-lobjc.6.0 => /usr/lib/libobjc.so.6.0
        20:-lkvm.16.1 => /usr/lib/libkvm.so.16.1
        21:-lreadline.4.0 => /usr/lib/libreadline.so.4.0
        22:-lskey.6.0 => /usr/lib/libskey.so.6.0
        23:-lsndio.6.1 => /usr/lib/libsndio.so.6.1
        24:-lsqlite3.32.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.32.0
        25:-lcrypto.37.0 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.37.0
        26:-lssl.38.0 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.38.0
        27:-lstdc++.57.0 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.57.0
        28:-ltermcap.14.0 => /usr/lib/libtermcap.so.14.0
        29:-lrpcsvc.2.0 => /usr/lib/librpcsvc.so.2.0
        30:-ltls.10.0 => /usr/lib/libtls.so.10.0
        31:-ltermlib.14.0 => /usr/lib/libtermlib.so.14.0
        32:-lmenuw.6.0 => /usr/lib/libmenuw.so.6.0
        33:-lusbhid.7.0 => /usr/lib/libusbhid.so.7.0
        34:-lutil.12.1 => /usr/lib/libutil.so.12.1
        35:-lz.5.0 => /usr/lib/libz.so.5.0
        36:-lm.9.0 => /usr/lib/libm.so.9.0
```

Comment: Seems you're missing some headers : `In file included from sf_iph.c:29:
../decode.h:48:17: error: daq.h: No such file or directory
../decode.h:49:23: error: sfbpf_dlt.h: No such file or directory` Perhaps it's a good start.

Comment: See my updated post of the install of daq, is there some other kind of header information that I need to add? How can I find the documentation for that? Could this be related to daq not showing up in ldconfig? Thank you

Comment: Please paste the output of `ldconfig`

Comment: @schaiba updated.

Comment: So ldconfig searches in /usr/lib . Perhaps you need to tell it to have a look in /usr/local/lib .

Comment: OpenBSD has a port for DAQ 2.0.6 (`daq-2.0.6`). `libpcap` is part of the base system on OpenBSD. Install DAQ from ports and try compiling again.

Comment: @schaiba I've ran the command `ldconfig -m -r -v /usr/local/lib` with the same results afterwards.

Comment: @Kusalananda that had me thinking that might have been it, but after installing it, I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

To compile and install Barnyard2 on OpenBSD you need to install the following ports, either from `/usr/ports` or as binary packages (I compile ports from sources so I don't know about the availability of binary packages). I'm listing the "base name" as well as the specific port names with version numbers that I have installed on my OpenBSD-current system.

- `libtool`; `libtool-2.4.2p0`
- `automake`; `automake-1.15p0` (will also pull in `autoconf-2.69p2`)
- `daq`; `daq-2.0.6`
- `libdnet`; `libdnet-1.12p13` (Barnyard2 uses headers from here, but doesn't seem to link with the `libdnet` library)

I'm also using GNU Stow (`stow-2.2.2`, I happen to maintain that port on OpenBSD) which allows you to install and maintain 3rd-party software easily under a custom *prefix* (I use `$HOME/local` below).

Get Barnyard2:

```
$ mkdir tmpbuild
$ cd tmpbuild
$ git clone git@github.com:firnsy/barnyard2.git
$ cd barnyard2
```

Set `AUTOCONF_VERSION` and `AUTOMAKE_VERSION` to the appropriate versions:

```
$ export AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.69
$ export AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.15
```

Run `autoreconf` (they have a `autogen.sh` script in there that you could use too, but I'm not):

```
$ autoreconf -i
```

Configure, pointing the preprocessor and linker to the appropriate directories under `/usr/local`:

```
$ ./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib --prefix=$HOME/local/stow/barnyard2
```

Build and install:

```
$ make clean && make
$ make install
$ cd $HOME/local/stow
$ stow -v barnyard2
```

Barnyard2 is now available as `$HOME/local/bin/barnyard2` with its configuration files (`dpb.hosts` and `barnyard2.conf`) in `$HOME/local/etc`.

NOTE: I've never *ever* had to fiddle with `ldconfig`.